# PHP cURL through proxy

Tags: php, curl, proxy, http-headers, http-status-codes

I'm trying to send a cURL request through a proxy in PHP.

```
$c = curl_init();
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $this->url);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_PROXY, $this->proxy);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->browser);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $requestData);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
$result = curl_exec($c);
```

And here are the errors I get:

> HTTP_CODE: 201 (ID: 511a59debf97b)
>   HTTP_CODE: 201 (ID: 511a59e25bc89)
>   HTTP_CODE: 201 (ID: 511a59e47797c)
>   HTTP_CODE: 201 (ID: 511a59e641246)
>   HTTP_CODE: 400 (ID: 511a59e9850dc)
>   HTTP_CODE: 400 (ID: 511a59ea59bda)
>   HTTP_CODE: 400 (ID: 511a59eb90572)
>   HTTP_CODE: 201 (ID: 511a59ec647ad)
>   HTTP_CODE: 411 (ID: 511a59efda30a)
>   HTTP_CODE: 201 (ID: 511a59f0c6c70)

As you can see, they're all 2xx and 4xx and I've no idea why this is so. I should probably also mention that sometimes (about 1/8 of all requests) the requests "work", so it fulfils the purpose of this script but it still logs this kind of errors.

Here's the error log code

```
#check for errors
$errorsFile = $this->folders["root"].$this->folders["db"].$this->files["errors"];
if(curl_errno($c)) file_put_contents($errorsFile, "CURL_ERRNO: ".curl_errno($c)." (ID: ".$this->requestID.")\n", FILE_APPEND);
else {
    $httpCode = curl_getinfo($c, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); #checks http status
    if($httpCode != 200) file_put_contents($errorsFile, "HTTP_CODE: ".$httpCode." (ID: ".$this->requestID.")\n", FILE_APPEND);
}
curl_close($c);
#log
$log = str_replace("\n", "", date("d.m.Y - H:i", time()) . " " . $this->proxy . " [" . $this->browser . "] (ID: ".$this->requestID.")")."\n" ;
file_put_contents($this->folders["root"].$this->folders["db"].$this->files["logs"], $log, FILE_APPEND);
```

As you can see, I also log cURL errors (if they happen) but they rarely happen.

However, I'm not sure where these errors come from and why it works sometimes and sometimes it doesn't. If there's something wrong with the proxy, I should get a cURL error not a HTTP error, right? So what's wrong?

**UPDATE**
Thanks to @Dharmavir

> proxy seems to be a problem here. Can you add a header in cURL request
>    with "Content-Length: ". I have experience in
>    past that sometimes proxy or firewall (ipcop in my case) blocked
>    requests w/o content length headers and considered as virus or bad
>    requests.

I didn't mention that `$proxy` is randomly chosen and therefore always a different one. I tested manually a proxy that worked and it handled all 10 of 10 requests successfully.

Comment: you should be logging the request data/url. especially for the 400/411 ones. 400 = bad request, 411 = length required.

Comment: proxy seems to be a problem here. Can you add a header in cURL request with "Content-Length: <strlen($requestData)>". I have experience in past that sometimes proxy or firewall (ipcop in my case) blocked requests w/o content length headers and considered as virus or bad requests.

Comment: What proxy is it? Can you configure the proxy or is it a 'black box' for you?

Comment: @hek2mgl nope, can't configure anything. it fetches randomly proxies from a proxylist website..

Comment: But the results you posted above are all from one single proxy? or different proxies?

Comment: @Dharmavir thanks! i've just figured out that the proxy is the problem. my script choses randomly a proxy, i set now a proxy that i tested manually and all 10 of 10 requests worked perfectly. i'll try to set a better header

Comment: @hek2mgl all different proxies

Comment: :) hehe. Than you have your answer. Btw, I would have added this 'detail' to the question